# How to access devices through sysfs?

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, sysfs

I am looking for a tutorial or example code that will help me understand how to work with sysfs in linux. I am a total beginner in this area and as such, will appreciate any help I can get.

My end goal is to write an application that will let me read/write data to an SPI EEPROM using the at25 driver.

So far, I have looked at the tutorial given at http://www.signal11.us/oss/udev/ and also at the [libudev](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/kernel/hotplug/libudev/index.html) page at kernel.org, but they didn't help me much.

What good sites/articles/examples should I refer to get a deeper understanding about how sysfs works and how to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sysfs is a representation of *kernel objects*, which are a basic property tree containing configuration data. I'd rather not use these for user data, but instead write a device driver, providing `read` and `write` *filesystem operations*.

Comment: So, just to be clear, should these read and write functions be for the EEPROM or the host-pc filesystem ? And what other resources are available to understand how sysfs works (just for personal clarity) ?

Comment: Your device driver would provide a [`file_operations`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/fs.h#L1583) structure with the functions that implement whatever you want your driver to do (e.g. read from the EEPROM). User programs can then `open()` your device and invoke `read()`/`write()` to talk to your driver.

Comment: Sorry took this long to accept the answer. I didn't realize the answer had remained unaccepted for so long!